# Integrating Facebook login with own user database

Tags: php, facebook

Maybe a 1000 times asked question but I could not find and sophisticated answer.

I have a PHP/MySQL user login system (session based) with a own users database. The structure features some user data like age, about me etc.

I can do this all in the means of programming, no problem, however - I have some "concept" issues that I hoped someone could advise me at:

1. Let's say that my user database features some field that FB does not cover. Should I ask for them let's say when the user first logs in with FB?
2. Better to take the profile PIC and save it locally or read it from remote server?
3. Better to save the FB data (like name, about me etc.) locally or read it from remote server all the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let's say that my user database features some field that FB does not cover. Should I ask for them let's say when the user first logs in with FB?

It would be rather nice to allow user to add them later or prompt them that their few information can be updated

> Better to take the profile PIC and save it locally or read it from remote server?

Depends, if you want to display the profile pic of the user to reflect his present state then use the profile image link and if you have the space to store all the image of the users then it is better to go with the local storage, although it might not be updated, but you can add selection option to upload new.

> Better to save the FB data (like name, about me etc.) locally or read it from remote server all the time?

Now for this I would suggest that you make the copy of the information you have retrieved locally, for the purpose of speed, cause getting the values back again and again takes toll on the page speed and hence the user experience.

Answer (score 0):

1) I would stick with some defaults and avoid requiring much of a user who may just want to browse around at first and let them fill in later when they get more involved and want to share.

2) I thought the facebook profile pic was a url dependent on user id. just attach the user id into an image link.

3) I think there are some rules about the data you can save and the data you cannot; a bit faster to serve it up if you already have it, but it can grow stale. So probably fetch it again after 24 hours or some other reasonable time frame. i.e. keep it in a cache, and fetch again if stale, clear your cache if stale to make room for more recent queries.